Why do Gemini models perform different on the web vs via API
I am using the free plan of Gemini on its web app to search for apple's latest stock price. The free plan uses Gemini 1.5 Flash and I get the answer no problem

However, when I try Gemini API, no matter which model I use (Flash or Pro), it always say it is a chatbot and does not have real-time information. I tried multiple times and one time it shows the price of Apple on Feb 2023. I asked the model what is it cutoff date and it said it is updated frequently and there is no cutoff date.

I wonder why there is a difference in the response between the web app and the API? I thought they use the same models?
